# 1 day left to fulfill your commitment!

Tags: discussion, participation

Users that "committed" to this site before it was launched into Beta, promised to write at least 10 questions or 10 answers within the first 6 months of Beta.

Users that fulfill their commitment are permanently acknowledged for their contribution:

[image]

And users that don't, have "Matter Modeling" disappear from their commitments page (for example I followed and committed to the Drones proposal, but neither of them show up, because I wasn't able to fulfill my commitment there.

Many users are very close to fulfilling their commitment, needing to write only 1 or 2 more answers:

[image]

This is just a friendly reminder that when we reach our 180th day in Beta, it will never again be possible to "fulfill" your commitment.